# Math for the "universe in a black hole" hypothesis?

Tags: black-hole, big-bang-theory, mathematics, multiverse

There are various pop-science article entitled [Are we living in a Black Hole?](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/2/140218-black-hole-blast-explains-big-bang/) or [Did A Black Hole Give Birth To Our Universe?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2020/11/03/did-a-black-hole-give-birth-to-our-universe/) which say things like

> There’s a lot to like about the idea that there’s a connection between black holes and the birth of Universes, from both physical and mathematical points of view. It’s plausible that there’s a connection between the birth of our Universe and the creation of an extremely massive black hole from a Universe that existed before our own; it’s plausible that every black hole that’s been created in our Universe has given rise to a new Universe within it.

What exactly are the mathematical connections? Are those calculations in any way connected to the [Black hole information paradoxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox)?

#### Background

I remember one of my professors for theoretical physics giving an evening lecture on the subject. He performed some lenghty and incredible fast calculations with chalk on blackbord. This lecture is long ago, in the age before smart phones, and I do not have records on his equations, that why I am asking here. What I do remember is that he concluded his lecture with something like "These are all convincing mathematical equations, but only once you jump into a black hole, you could see whether there are other universes there."

#### References

- [How is information preserved on the surface of a Black Hole?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29149/preserve-information-in-a-black-hole)
- [New Theory Suggests We Live in a Gigantic Higher Dimensional Black Hole](https://themindunleashed.com/2019/06/universe-higher-dimensional-black-hole.html)
- Many articles refer to [Prof. Nikodem Popławski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikodem_Pop%C5%82awski) in one way or the other.
- [Some physicists believe we're living in a giant hologram — and it's not that far-fetched](https://www.vox.com/2015/6/29/8847863/holographic-principle-universe-theory-physics)

Comment: I added the tag [mathematics](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) not because I have many equations in my question - but as I would love to see some on the topic.